# I cant change my tables name in existing database with dbcontext and migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, migration, database-migration, dbcontext

I am trying changing tabel name, I have a database and one table with name BarMenu.
BarMenu has data. How I can do that. I tried migration AutoCreating model builder. And some example cod below. Ty for Helping.

```
public class GxptBulutEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BarMenu> BarMenuler { get; set; }
    public GxptBulutEntities()
        : base("GxptBulutEntities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<GxptBulutEntities, Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BarMenu>().ToTable("BarMenuler");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<GxptBulutEntities>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(GxptBulutEntities context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing table, you can't use migrations, so you must turn off database initialization on your context:

```
public GxptBulutEntities()
    : base("GxptBulutEntities")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<GxptBulutEntities>(null);
}
```